# Chilled puff pastry vs frozen

Tags: puff-pastry

Just found out there's actually two kind of puff pastry in my local supermarket, one called chilled and one called frozen. Do anyone know the difference?

Some people said the chilled one is fresher as it's kept in normal fridge not frozen. But then I'd also want to know if I have left over of this chilled puff pastry sheet can I freeze them for storage?

Answer (score 3):

Chilled means refrigerated, and frozen is frozen.  The first is for shoppers who want to use the pastry dough right away, and the frozen is for most shoppers who aren't using it immediately.

You can freeze puff pastry.  In fact, you can freeze and thaw it a couple of times before the freezing/thawing process starts to ruin the dough.

Comment: How do you thaw it in a reasonable amount of time without getting the outer layers too warm?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "reasonable".  The best way to thaw it is in the fridge, because you don't want the butter (or shortening) in the puff pastry to melt, which would ruin it.  Thawing it in a 16C room would also be OK, but not really any warmer than that.

Comment: If the puff pastry is tightly sealed in plastic packs, you could conceivably thaw it in cold water (NOT warm water), but I don't know any brand which is packaged that way.

Comment: Thawing anything in the fridge usually takes longer than remaking it :)